# how to vertically allign bootstrap button with a Google hangout button

Tags: css

I have a problem where I want to have a bootstrap button and a Google Hangout button next to each other but the Google hangout button has some align issues and I have not been able to get them to align up.

[image: Google Button Bootstrap button]

I have tried wrapping the Google button in a `span` and applying some `margin-top` to it but nothing seems to change it. Anyone have any clues?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> <?=_("Create")?> <i class="fab fa-google" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?=_("Calendar Event")?></button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<g:hangout render="createhangout"
    invites="[{ id : '<?=$username?>', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]">
</g:hangout>
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below, maybe u can use `float` on calendar event

```
<div style="float:left;padding:0 10px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> <?=_("Create")?> <i class="fab fa-google" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?=_("Calendar Event")?></button>
</div>
<div style="padding:0 10px;">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
    <g:hangout render="createhangout"
    invites="[{ id : '<?=$username?>', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]">
    </g:hangout>
</div>
```